# USA visitors visa in old passport

Tags: usa, passport-renewals

I shall travel to Mexico and then to the USA with a Lesotho passport.
I have a 6 hour layover in London at Heathrow airport out of South Africa.
I have a US visa in an old passport which is still valid until 2019.

1. DO I need a transit airside visa for London - I will not require to pass through customs/passport control while waiting at Heathrow.
2. DO I need to have my US visa transferred into my new passport before I leave home?  - Nothing has changed, such as my names in the new passport.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, your US visa allows airside transit in the UK, no matter where you're flying to (see [here](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/lesotho/transit/somewhere_else/no))
2. No, just carry both passports, and present both at check-in, and to the US Immigration Officer (see [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html), "My old passport has already expired. My visa to travel to the United States is still valid but in my expired passport. Do I need to apply for a new visa with my new passport?")

Answer (score 0):

1. No. https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/lesotho/transit/somewhere_else/no
2. No. The US visa is valid independent of passport validity. Make sure you have an old passport with you.